# What's Ruby one-liner equivalent to awk's RS, NF, and OFS?

Tags: ruby, awk

I have this file:

```
1
2
3
4


a
b
c

XY
Z
```

I want to convert every block into a `TAB` separated line, and append the current `timestamp` at the last column to get an output like this:

```
1   2   3   4   1548915098
a   b   c   1548915098
XY  Z   1548915098
```

I can use `awk` to do it like this:

```
awk '$(NF+1)=systime()' RS= OFS="\t" file
```

where empty `RS` is equivalent to set `RS="\n\n+"`.

But I want to use Ruby one-liner to do it. I've come up with this:

```
ruby -a -ne 'BEGIN{@lines=Array.new}; if ($_ !~ /^$/) then @lines.push($_.chomp) else (puts @lines.push(Time.now.to_i.to_s).join "\t"; @lines=Array.new) unless @lines.empty? end; END{puts @lines.push(Time.now.to_i.to_s).join "\t" unless @lines.empty?}' file
```

which is somehow awkward.

Is there any elegant way to do this?
And are there any `ruby` equivalents to `awk`'s `RS`, `NF`, and `OFS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '$(NF+1)=systime()' RS= OFS="\t" ip.txt
1   2   3   4   1548917728
a   b   c   1548917728
XY  Z   1548917728

$ # .to_s can be ignored here, since puts will take care of it
$ ruby -00 -lane '$F.append(Time.now.to_i.to_s); puts $F.join("\t")' ip.txt
1   2   3   4   1548917730
a   b   c   1548917730
XY  Z   1548917730
```

- `-00` paragraph mode
- `-a` auto split, results available from `$F` array
- `-l` chomps record separator

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer and elegant way.  I missed the `-0` switch.  Is the `0` after it represents newline?

Comment: there are plenty of nuances for `-0` switch, so I'll just link to my [Ruby one-liners tutorial](https://github.com/learnbyexample/Command-line-text-processing/blob/master/ruby_one_liners.md#input-record-separator)

Comment: Thanks for the link :)